# specifying div height (bootstrap)

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

so I am trying to make a cool portfolio landing page with Bootstrap.

The template includes a fixed navbar and a sticky footer. The rest of the page is whtespace that I want to fill with basically a giant background so I put a test paragraph element to try and see how to size it. I figured I could just add CSS rules that made body's height 100% but when I do that I get an overflow and my footer isn't at the bottom of the page anymore. Instead I have a small overflow of the background at the bottom.

How can I fix this? I made the background color bright yellow to try and show what I mean. Any help is appreciated!

Here's the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
<title>Work in Progress</title>
</head>

<body>
<!--navbar-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" 
                data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" 
                aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Portfolio</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse" 
                aria-expanded="false" style="height: 1px;">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" 
          role="button" aria-haspopup="true" 
          aria-expanded="false">Projects 
          <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Rails Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">LAMP Projects</a></li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>    
</nav>


<div class="main">
<div class="container">
<p>Test text</p>
</div>
</div>



<!--footer-->
<footer class="footer">
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4">
   <p>Contact info or whatever goes here.</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
   <p>More info or whatever goes here.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</footer>


</body>
</html>
```

And here's the CSS

```
html, body{
height: 100%
}

.main{
height: 100%;
background-color: #FFFF00;
margin-top: 50px;
}

.footer{
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
background-color: #000;
color: #9d9d9d;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this CSS (`position: relative` on body and `.main` height as calc function (100% minus height of the footer):

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.main {
  height: calc(100% - 60px);
  background-color: #FFFF00;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #9d9d9d;
}
```

Comment: So I tried this code out. It works in that there is no whitespace at the bottom anymore but now it forces a user to have to use the scrollbar to even see the footer at the bottom.

Comment: I updated the code, use `padding-top` instead of `margin-top`.

Comment: Combined your idea and the above idea to get it to work. You correctly pointed out that it should be the height minus the footer and. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Demo: https://fiddle.jshell.net/uvaef49h/1/

You want to use the following CSS:

```
    html, body{
height: 100%;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

.main{
height: calc(100% - 110px);
background-color: #FFFF00;
margin-top: 50px;
}

.footer{
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
background-color: #000;
color: #9d9d9d;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Why did it not work before?

The body had a height of X, main occupied 100% of that. However main was pushed down by the `50px` margin. After the `.main` part, you had your footer which was completely pushed out from the view-port so I had to remove another `60px` from `.main`s height. The footer still had an overflow issue so I hid that.

Lastly, the browser wanted to add some random margin/padding so I Removed that as well.

Comment: I tried out this code. All that happened for me was that the extra space became white instead of yellow at the bottom.

Comment: Ok so by changing the calc to - 60px instead of -110px it works now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ricksanchez If it helped, please accept this answer